# Sending a Push Notification to Android Application Users

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have created an android application for which i want to send push notification to the app users using GCM. Have read that GCM doesn't use Mobile numbers to send notification to app users. My question is that how can i use GCM to send notification to specific users,and also can some one help with procedure of setting up GCM for android Apps?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: first read full documentation properly..

Comment: @sharayu Try to be more precise with your question so that it will be easy to assist. To answer you question, first you gotta create google project to setup notifications and then you gotta register your device to the project and then the reg id will be used for sending notifications. Read the GCM docs for more info

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should read the documentation as Aditay Said.

GCM communicates with your app using your pacakge signature and app id which you provided in googole developer console.

Here is a helpful link for you , This will help you to achieve your goal

https://neurobin.org/docs/android/push-notification-gcm-client-server/

N.B: Don't forget to accept my answer if you got your answer